# Filter large data using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am starting to use Powershell and trying to filter out large info to just a few lines which i would like. Not sure of the exact syntax to do this. I have a large SSIS package (dtsx format) and trying to get the lines which start with "openrowset" to show which table is being loaded or "SQLTASK:SslStatementSource" to know what additional logic is being ran. Is this possible to filter down. Currently thousands of lines are being printed.
My current code is

```
get-content Z:\Database\SSIS\TestStg.dtsx
```

Sample [image: Sample Data]

Comment: AFAIK a .dtsx file is in XML format (Data Transformation Services Package XML), so I would not recommend string search methods on it. Can you show us a valid representation of that file?

Comment: I added an image if how the data looks. The code goes on for 1000s of line so just small sample size. This may not be possible but just something which would help if it was

Comment: @tomfbsc None of those lines start with "openrowset"?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sorry the above was the sample for starting with 'SQLTASK:SqlStatementSource'. It would be similar looking for the openrowset code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Select-String` regex command:

```
Select-String -LiteralPath Z:\Database\SSIS\TestStg.dtsx -Pattern '^\s*openrowset'
```

The regex pattern `^\s*openrowset` describes:

```
^           # start of string/line
\s*         # zero or more whitespace characters
openrowset  # the literal word "openrowset"
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, when i try it i get the following error. Not sure if i am missing any components or that. "Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Pattern'. " Was using the logic get-content Z:\Database\SSIS\Archive\package.dtsx -Pattern '^\s*openrowset'

Comment: @tomfbsc You're clearly still running `Get-Content`, not `Select-String` :)

Comment: Sorry i missed that at the beginning, Thanks for all your help it works great.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out .DTSX is an XML format so you should parse it as XML using XPath rather than attempting to do it with string parsing.

This Powershell script should demonstrate returning the values for the OpenRowset attributes.

Note: I'm not really a Powershell expert so this could well be done in a better way.

```
[xml]$dtsx = Get-Content "my-dtsx-file.dtsx"

# Add the namespace.
$ns = new-object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $dtsx.NameTable
$ns.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")

# The XPath in question is
# /DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable[1]/DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component[x]/properties/property[y]/@name
$properties = $dtsx.SelectNodes("//property", $ns) 

foreach ($node in $properties)
{
    if ($node.name -eq "OpenRowset")
    {
        Write-Host $node.InnerXml
    }
}
```

Comment: @[Alan B] I gave it ago but got the following error:  Not sure where i have gone wrong on it. I am completely new to PowerShell so it could just be an error i have included.   
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $ns.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull